# What is the equation for this combination calculation anonymous function and how can I work it out?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, combinations

I need to derive the equation knowing only inputs and outputs but not operations.

The question is: How can I get, and what is, the mathematical equation (using calculus, if possible) to calculate the $result$ given any $x$ and any $y$?

Below is the output of a computer program to calculate maximum possible combinations, given $x$ possible inputs, but only $y$ possible spaces in the vector, with no duplication, and all spaces in the vector being filled.

There is a constraint in that $y <= x$ (there is never more spaces in vector of length $y$ than there is data available in vector of length $x$).  Additionally, I don't know if this is important, but it seems that when $x$ is even, $y<=x-2$ and $y>=2$ then $result$ is divisible by $x-1$.

Cases where $x=y$, $y=0$, $y=x-1$, or $y=1$ are not important, since the answer to those specific cases are always either $1$, $0$, $x$ or $x$ respectively.

For example, given x=4 inputs, and y=2 spaces in the vector, there are 6 possible outcomes: 1. 0011 2. 0101 3. 0110 4. 1001 5. 1010 6. 1100.  Note, in this example, the 1's represent the index in the vector of length $x$ which has been selected for insertion into vector of length $y$, rather than the value.

---

```
f(x=1,y=1) = 1
f(x=1,y=0) = 0

f(x=2,y=2) = 1
f(x=2,y=1) = 2
f(x=2,y=0) = 0

f(x=3,y=3) = 1
f(x=3,y=2) = 3
f(x=3,y=1) = 3
f(x=3,y=0) = 0

f(x=4,y=4) = 1
f(x=4,y=3) = 4
f(x=4,y=2) = 6
f(x=4,y=1) = 4
f(x=4,y=0) = 0

f(x=5,y=5) = 1
f(x=5,y=4) = 5
f(x=5,y=3) = 10
f(x=5,y=2) = 10
f(x=5,y=1) = 5
f(x=5,y=0) = 0

f(x=6,y=6) = 1
f(x=6,y=5) = 6
f(x=6,y=4) = 15
f(x=6,y=3) = 20
f(x=6,y=2) = 15
f(x=6,y=1) = 6
f(x=6,y=0) = 0

f(x=7,y=7) = 1
f(x=7,y=6) = 7
f(x=7,y=5) = 21
f(x=7,y=4) = 35
f(x=7,y=3) = 35
f(x=7,y=2) = 21
f(x=7,y=1) = 7
f(x=7,y=0) = 0

f(x=8,y=8) = 1
f(x=8,y=7) = 8
f(x=8,y=6) = 28
f(x=8,y=5) = 56
f(x=8,y=4) = 70
f(x=8,y=3) = 56
f(x=8,y=2) = 28
f(x=8,y=1) = 8
f(x=8,y=0) = 0

f(x=9,y=9) = 1
f(x=9,y=8) = 9
f(x=9,y=7) = 36
f(x=9,y=6) = 84
f(x=9,y=5) = 126
f(x=9,y=4) = 126
f(x=9,y=3) = 84
f(x=9,y=2) = 36
f(x=9,y=1) = 9
f(x=9,y=0) = 0

f(x=10,y=10) = 1
f(x=10,y=9) = 10
f(x=10,y=8) = 45
f(x=10,y=7) = 120
f(x=10,y=6) = 210
f(x=10,y=5) = 252
f(x=10,y=4) = 210
f(x=10,y=3) = 120
f(x=10,y=2) = 45
f(x=10,y=1) = 10
f(x=10,y=0) = 0
```

---

Additional materials / supplement: if useful or interesting, here is the program which calculated the numbers:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
        {
            for (var y = x; y >= 0; y--)
            {
                var combinations_of_x_in_y = 0;

                for (Int64 i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt64(new string('1', x), 2); i++)
                {
                    var binary_str = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(x, '0');

                    var total_true = binary_str.Count(n => n == '1');

                    if (total_true == y)
                    {
                        combinations_of_x_in_y++;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("f(x="+x + ",y=" + y + ") = " + combinations_of_x_in_y);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Those are just binomial coefficients, except for the case y = 0

Comment: Hint: almost (but not quite) the binomial theorem.

Comment: Yes.  You are right, they are binomial coefficients.  I checked C(x,y) to compare the results.  However, please could you tell me or give a link, what is the formula for C(x,y), is there a simple variant of the formula?  Thank you!

Comment: Also, is there a methodology to solve this problem having only inputs and outputs to derive the equation?  What if we didn't know about binomials, how would the problem be solved, is it possible?

Comment: @Aalawlx, the formulas for C(x,y) can be found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). There are many many different tools to answer questions like "what formula generates these numbers?" There's statistcal modeling, combinatorics ( for when you have the code like this), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments suggest, these are binomial coefficients and solved by C(x,y).

Note: If a specific combination needs an answer Wolfram Alpha can solve C(x,y).